# Temporary session using flask login module

Tags: python, ios, session, flask, flask-login

How do I create/maintain temporary session in an iOS application whose backend is powered by Flask. I use flask-login module for user session management. I want to let users try out my iOS application without users signing-up/signing-in. My app's behavior, when a user is anonymous, is similar to when a user is logged in.

I want to use user's device token as unique id. Is it possible to create a session with just device token (usually we provide user id and password)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the device token is guaranteed to be unique and that the relationship between users and devices is one-to-one (although this could be adapted to work with a one-to-many situation as well):

```
@app.route("/authenticate", methods=("POST",))
def authenticate():
    if request.form.get("user_id") is not None:
        user = authenticate_user(request.form)
    else:
        user = create_user_for_device(request.form)

    login_user(user)
    # And so on
```

`authenticate_user` and `create_user_for_device` are functions that you will have to write - [`login_user`](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#flask.ext.login.login_user) is from Flask-Login.